# InstallShield - How to install redist from setup ini command

Tags: installshield

I have an installshield project is it possible to install redistributable packages after the main install process ends?

I can't modify the package so I would run the installer from setup.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use a custom action which launches the prerequisites asynchronously and doesn't wait for them to finish.

But if you can't modify the package, the only solution I can think of is a BAT file. This BAT can first execute the package and then the prerequisites.

Comment: Prerequisites installed by InstallShield are always installed BEFORE the actual setup runs. If you want to inject this in an existing setup is this at least not the official way, but it is possible to add prerequisites to the setup.ini file. If you don't know how to do that manually you can simply create an installshield setup with the desired prerequisites frim IS IDE and copy the prerequisites from the ini and ISSetupPrerequsites-Folder.

Comment: That's only true for Setup Prereqs.  Feature Prereqs get installed later after feature selection has occurred on an as needed basis.

Comment: I didn't know that. Nice to know. But in this case I guess that Feature Prerequisites are stored in the cab files and not in the package. Maybe this is the trick.

Comment: They are also moving away from all of this and pushing Suite installers (similar to WiX Burn)

Answer (score 0):

Setup.ini isn't designed to support injecting additional instals.  You'd have to write another wrapper install that could chain this install and your other install together.

Comment: This is not true, it is at least not the official way, but it is not problem to add prerequisites to the setup.ini file if you know how to do it and if you want the same functionality IS provides (Prerequisites are installed before the actual setup runs)

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail... maybe IS has changed it's design in the last 3 years?   Yes the setup.ini as an ISPrereqs section but the .prq file isn't kept in the folder it's embedded into the setup.exe.  AFAIK there's no way to just tag on another one.  MichaelU would be able to say for certain.

Comment: I will check this tommorrow. AFAIK the setup.exe is never compiled by IS IDE. Everything is in the cab files except for the prerequisites. There is a folder called ISSetupPrerequisites. Maybe this was changed in some older version. We use Prerequisites in this way since IS 2011.

Comment: The ISPRQ folder only has the prereq content not the PRQ itself.  The EXE gets various embedded resources and water markings such as copyright and digital signatures.  In some scenarios (self extracting EXE) absolutely everything is in the EXE.  I've asked InstallShield for years to have a tool to extract it all out, transform and recreate the EXE (all but digital certs)  but they have never done it.

Comment: At the moment I can confirm that in IS 2013 and IS 2014 the setup.ini points to the prq and the prq is located in the ISSetupPrerequisites Folder in the Disk folder.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know.